# Tax obligation for money transfer to France for non French residents

Tags: taxes, non-resident, france

My wife and I are both US citizens and live in the US. My wife is also French citizen. We have a joint account held in a French bank. We also own an apartment in France that we never lived in (it is presently unoccupied). We are not French residents (we've lived full time in the US for many years).

I am the sole owner of an apartment in another EU country (not France) that I intend to sell and the proceeds in Euro to be transferred to our French joint account.

I know that the capital gains will have to be declared to the IRS, but do I have any obligations toward France - do I have to declare anything, and will we have to pay any taxes on the sale, transfer or anything else to the French government?